# Ternary statement to define what we pass to astype()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

OK so I'm working with someone else's code and see that it leads to lots of issues because it aggregates astype(int) when making several calculations. This is usually the right thing to do, but in certain cases, it leads to pretty substantial rounding errors.

So in theory what I'd like to do is something like `df.column.astype(float) if something==something else .astype(int)`.

I can break up the aggregation method (currently it's essentially `return df.groupby(stuff).agg(otherstuff).astype(int)`), but I'm hoping someone can help me find a better, more efficient solution

I've tried using ternary statements, rearranging the code to make it accommodate for more edge cases, etc. But I feel like there's a much cleaner, more elegant solution for this sort of issue that I simply don't have the knowledge/experience to think of

Comment: `.astype(float if condition else int)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jonesharpe said in his comment, you can use a [ternary condition](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) which chooses what type will be sent.

```
.astype(float if something==something else int)
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that....what the hell is wrong with me. Maybe it's the lack of sleep with a newborn....thanks!